# How to get csv file noderef by using the file name or file path in alfresco webscript

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am very new in alfresco, and i am struggling in reading csv file from alfresco repository.

I have one CSV file in alfresco repository, data dictionary folder. 
now my requirement is to get the noderef of the csv file and read the all data from csv file.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Do you want to read the file in webscript in Repo side or Share side ? Provide bit more information + some code that you've tried.

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan Repo side, i have to write 1 java backed webscript, through that i want to get the file node ref and have to read content from that csv file

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lucene query to get document using name like

```
1)alfresco Node Browser Query :   +PATH:"/app:company_home//* " AND +@cm\:name:"abc.txt"

2)alfresco share javascript query : var nodes = nodes = search.luceneSearch("@cm\\:name:\"abc.txt\"");

3)alfresco java backed webscript query : 
        String query ="PATH:\"/app:company_home//*\"";
        query+="@cm\\:name:abc.txt";


        StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE,"SpacesStore");

        ResultSet results = searchService.query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE, query);

           for (ResultSetRow row : results) {
              NodeRef currentNodeRef = row.getNodeRef();
              lista.add(currentNodeRef.toString());

           }
```

make changes in query as per your requrement.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will return the noderef as you are expecting from the folder/file path.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        client = new AlfrescoClient.Builder().connect("http://localhost:8080/alfresco", "admin", "admin").build();
        NodeRepresentation node = findNodeByPath("Sites/testsite/documentLibrary/TestFolder/UploadTest.txt");
        System.out.println(node == null ? "null" : node.getName());
    }

private static NodeRepresentation findNodeByPath(String path) throws IOException {
    if (path.startsWith("/"))
        path = path.substring(1);
    if (path.endsWith("/"))
        path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1);
    return findNodeByPath("-root-", path);
}

private static NodeRepresentation findNodeByPath(String parentNodeId, String path) throws IOException {
    String[] pathParts = path.split("/");
    String name = pathParts[0];
    String remaining = pathParts.length == 1 ? "" : path.substring(name.length() + 1, path.length());
    List<NodeRepresentation> children = client.getNodesAPI().listNodeChildrenCall(parentNodeId).execute().body()
            .getList();
    for (NodeRepresentation child : children) {
        if (child.getName().equals(name)) {
            return pathParts.length == 1 ? child : findNodeByPath(child.getId(), remaining);
        }
    }
return null;
```